# Issue with bing map inside a scrollviewer

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing-maps, scrollviewer

I have a bing map which is located inside a scrollviewer along with a listbox.

Now the problem is when the content of the scrollviewer is scrolled down, "Bing map is rendered on top of other elements which are located above scrollviewer (outside the boundary of scrollviewer)"

```
<TextBlock Text="some text" />
<ScrollViewer>
    <map:Map ... />
    <ListBox ... />
</ScrollViewer>
```

What is wrong? Is it a known bug?
I'm trying to include a small map in my search result list box (the same as windows phone bing result page 'local' pivot item does)

Some observations:
(1) only bing map tile images are rendered on top (not even pushpins) 
(2) the elements that are located beneath the scrollviewer (in xaml) are correctly rendered on top of the map!

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally found a good workaround for it which make's it look awesome.
Here is the trick:

ONE. we disable the bing map tile images by adding the following line to the constructor of the page/usercontrol:

```
map.Mode.Content.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

TWO. Right before the map control we add a  element with the same width and height as map control:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Image .../>
        <map:Map .../>
    </Grid>
    <ListBox ... />
</ScrollViewer>
```

THREE. now we build up a BitmapImage for the Image element from "Bing static map API":
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx

```
var url = "<bing static map api url for my location and zoom level - without any pushpin>";
var uri = new Uri(url);
imgStaticMap.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

This way:

- we will have the same map (both are bing maps)
- the static map is show normally in the scroll bar
- It's even kinda better for this case, because this way there woul'nt be a loading effect on our small map (while the  has inevitable loading effect)

Answer (score 1):

Just don't put the Map in the scrollviewer.

This will also prevent issues with scrolling within the app.

Comment: Ofcourse that is a "Decision" which I will make if I have to.
But what I'm looking for here is a solution to this problem, or alternatively why this is happening, or if this is a known bug.

the OS itself has this effect (map inside scroll bar) in the 'local' tab of bing search result page.

Putting bing map outside the scroll viewer will waste alot of useful space on the screen.

Comment: The native apps aren't written in Silverlight and so have different restrictions on what can and can't be done. We have to work within the limits of what is exposed by the framework.

Comment: I know that not everything in native apps maybe possible to do in my app. But I'm not still convinced that this is impossible, because (1) only bing map tile image are rendered on top (not even pushpins) (2) the elements that are located beneath the scrollviewer (in xaml) are correctly rendered on top of the map!

Answer (score 0):

I use `JeffWilcox.Maps` component to similar purposes. This static maps works fine inside ScrollViewer.

- Blog http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/jeffwilcox-maps/
- Nuget    http://nuget.org/packages/JeffWilcox.Maps
- GitHub    https://github.com/jeffwilcox/wp-maps